# determine if user hit refresh button angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can I check I the user hit the refresh button on the angularjs app?

When the user hits the refresh button F5 on http://ip.us/angularjs/#/link/ the page http://ip.us/angularjs/#/link/ will be loaded again. I want to redirect the user to the startpage http://ip.us/angularjs/

I tried something with keyup and checked if the f5 key was pressed. But it's not a nice solution.

Is there something better to determine an refresh or reaload of the page?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Javascript onbeforeunload event:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return "Are you sure you wish to leave the page?";
}
```